# How to increase version of NPM package.json in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, npm, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to modify Jenkinsfile to bump the version of my NPM package before deploying the server.

I have this on the deploy method:

```
    if (env.GIT_COMMIT != env.GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT && env.GIT_BRANCH == "origin/develop"){         
        def version=sh(returnStdout: true, script: "npm version")
        echo "Version is ${version}"
        echo "${version.test}"
        sh "npm version patch"
        sh "git push"
    }
```

I am checking if my previous commit is different than the actual, so if there is any change between the last deploy and the current, it should increase the version number.

The version variable output is:

```
{
  test: '0.0.3',
  npm: '6.12.1',
  ares: '1.15.0',
  brotli: '1.0.7',
  cldr: '35.1',
  http_parser: '2.8.0',
  icu: '64.2',
  llhttp: '1.1.4',
  modules: '72',
  napi: '5',
  nghttp2: '1.39.2',
  node: '12.13.1',
  openssl: '1.1.1d',
  tz: '2019c',
  unicode: '12.1',
  uv: '1.33.1',
  v8: '7.7.299.13-node.16',
  zlib: '1.2.11'
}
```

I would like `test` to go from `0.0.3` to `0.0.4` and then use `npm version 0.0.4` to set that version in the app.

`${version.test}` is not working. It throws the following error:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field java.lang.String test
```

How can I get that value and increase it so I can use properly the `npm version 0.0.X` and then pushing it to the repository?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to parse it before getting any value. have you tried readJSON ?  https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace

Comment: yes, Its working now parsed to JSON. Now its failing in the push. I will edit the code asap