# Jenkins job needs to push updated file to remote git repo

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I am having a Jenkins job which would clone the repository from the GitHub, and then shall run the shell script which would increment the version number in the file. Now, I am trying to publish that update file back to the original repository on GitHub, so that when a developer pulls the changes, that person would get the latest version number.

I have spent lot of time finding solution for this.I Need a help

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59733254/7976758 ? Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjenkins-pipeline%5D+increase+version+push

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to delegate that task to a GitHub Action (no local Jenkins needed).

On any push, that action (hook executed on the Github server side) would be triggered and perform the bump.

Example: [`automated-version-bump`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/automated-version-bump) or [`increment-semantic-version`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/increment-semantic-version)